# How can I control the max_value of sg.ProgressBar?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm building a GUI with PySimpleGUI to run Chocolatey scripts.

I want to integrate a ProgressBar into it which will display the progress of the executed Scripts 1 by 1 and the max_value of the ProgressBar will be variable controlled.

For this example I have a list which contains the scripts:

```
predefined_package_list = ["choco install firefox --version 111.0.1 -y",
"choco install 7zip.install --version 22.1 -y",
"choco install vlc --version 3.0.18 -y"]
```

I made a function which counts the length of the list, loops through it and exectues the Script 1 by 1:

```
def predefined_choco_packages(package_list):
   count = 0
   
   for element in package_list:
      count += 1
      window["-OUTPUT-"].print(f"Running Script: {count}/{len(package_list)}")
      result = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", element], text = True) 
      window["-OUTPUT-"].print(result)
```

Now, I'm kinda having a hard time to figure out how to update the ProgressBar max_value in an event and then update it's progress too soo it reaches 100%. (Example the `predefined_package_list` variable has a count of 3, I want the ProgressBar value to be set to 3 in an event and then when one of the scripts in the Variable runs the ProgressBar goes to 33%, then 66% and finally 100%)

Here's my code snippet:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import subprocess

predefined_package_list = ["choco install firefox --version 111.0.1 -y",
"choco install 7zip.install --version 22.1 -y",
"choco install vlc --version 3.0.18 -y"]

pbar_value = 10 # Variable placeholder which will be updated by events and set as max_value for the ProgressBar

# Predefined Software Packages
def predefined_choco_packages(package_list):
   count = 0
   
   for element in package_list:
      count += 1
      window["-OUTPUT-"].print(f"Running Script: {count}/{len(package_list)}")
      result = subprocess.run(["powershell.exe", element], text = True) 
      window["-OUTPUT-"].print(result)

sg.theme("SystemDefault")
font = ("Arial", 16)

layout = [[sg.Text("Install Predefined Chocolatey Packages",font="Arial 16 bold"),sg.Button("Install Packages",size=(15,1))],
          [sg.Multiline(size=(90,10),key="-OUTPUT-")],
          [sg.Text("Progress:"),sg.ProgressBar(pbar_value, orientation= "h", bar_color="green",size=(70,25), key="-PBAR-"),sg.Button("Exit",size=(10,1),tooltip="Exit the Program.", expand_x=True)]]

window = sg.Window("Test",layout,font=font,finalize=True)

while True:
   event, values = window.read()
   #window["-OUTPUT-"].print(event,values)
   
   if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
      break
   
   if event == "Install Packages":
      
      pbar_value = len(predefined_package_list ) # Gets set to script size - in this instance this variable will be 3
      window["-PBAR-"].update(pbar_value) # This should update the max_value Parameter in sg.ProgressBar and set it to 3?
      
      for i in range(pbar_value):
         window["-PBAR-"].update(i+1)
         
      window.perform_long_operation(lambda: predefined_choco_packages(predefined_package_list ),"-OUTPUT-")
      
   elif event == "Clear Output":
      window["-OUTPUT-"].update("")
        
window.close()
```

**Please be mindful that in case of running the code, if you have Chocolatey by chance installed it will install the software in the script!**

I tried to set the variable before the event to `pbar_value = len(predefined_package_list )` then a update with `window["-PBAR-"].update(len(predefined_package_list )` and then a `for i in range(len(predefined_package_list )` loop to see if it worked, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `update` of element just update the architecture of tkinter/PysimpleGUI, not update the GUI immediately.

Try to call `window.refresh()` if you want the GUI updated immediately, not until back to `window.read()`.

The function `predefined_choco_packages` will be called in other thread by `window.perform_long_operation`, better change all GUI updates, like `window["-OUTPUT-"].print`, to `window.write_event_value`, then handle this event in your event loop.

Update the max value by `window["-PBAR-"].update(max=pbar_value)`.

Demo code

```py
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def func(window, job_list):
    for i, job in enumerate(job_list):
        sleep(job)      # simulate the job to do.
        window.write_event_value("JOB", i+1)
    window.write_event_value("JOB Done", None)

layout = [
    [sg.ProgressBar(10, orientation= "h", size=(40,25), key="-PROGRESS-"),
     sg.Text("00/00", size=5, key='-STEPS-')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("GO"), sg.Push()],
]
window = sg.Window('Demo', layout)
running = False

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "GO" and not running:
        running = True
        job_list = [randint(1, 10)/10 for i in range(randint(3, 20))]
        steps = len(job_list)
        window["GO"].update(disabled=True)
        window["-STEPS-"].update(f"00/{steps:0>2d}")
        window['-PROGRESS-'].update(current_count=0, max=steps)
        threading.Thread(target=func, args=(window, job_list), daemon=True).start()
    elif event == 'JOB':
        current_count = values[event]
        window["-STEPS-"].update(f"{current_count:0>2d}/{steps:0>2d}")
        window['-PROGRESS-'].update(current_count=current_count, max=len(job_list))
    elif event == 'JOB Done':
        running = False
        window["GO"].update(disabled=False)

window.close()
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for the answer now I understand more what you meant. I found a solution too, I just changed the function in the code and it works as expected, although I don't know how "Safe" it is. 

I added: `window["-PBAR-"].update(0,max=len(package_list))` `window["-PBAR-"].update(current_count= 0 + count)` and `time.sleep(0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

Your update command:  `window["-PBAR-"].update(pbar_value)`   should be `window["-PBAR-"].update(max=pbar_value)`
and your `window["-PBAR-"].update(i + 1)`  needs to be `window["-PBAR-"].update(current_count = i + 1)`

But you have a few problems that you quickly update all the current counts then allow the window to do another read; therefore the user will never see the update.  When you want the user to see the update, run `window.refresh()` or a `window.read()`.

P.S.  I think you want a key value on every button.  I recommend you make you install button look like: `sg.Button("Install Packages", size=(15, 1), key='-INSTALL-')`

Comment: I'm not sure where I should put the `window.refresh()`. I tried it in my event `Install Packages` above the `window.perform_long_operation` call, but it still instantly updated to Progressbar to the 5 items in the list and the `max_value` of `sg.Progressbar` is still 10, so the Progressbar was filled only to the half.

Comment: you put the refresh call right after the update call. Try these lines of code where you have the update command: `print(f"currently:{i} out of {pbar_value}")     window["-PBAR-"].update(max=pbar_value,current_count=i)     window.refresh()`